# Office 365 Connectors and Graph Data Extensions; pushing content to Delve from 3rd party systems

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365connectors

I am researching the available methods for surfacing content in Delve from external systems.

The only two options for pushing information into O365 that I can find are Office 365 Connectors and Graph Data Extensions (openTypeExtension resource type).

My questions are:

How are these technologies designed to work and will either of them be included in Graph -> Users -> Insights -> List trendingAround and List workingWith?

Is there a way to surface the Connector Cards in Delve?

Are there any other mechanisms available to include 3rd party data in Delve?

There was a session at Microsoft Ignite 2015 that demonstrated the features that I'm looking for, which were unavailable to the public at the time but it looks like that was before Connectors and Data extensions became available.

https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3193

From the description: "We’ll also demonstrate how you in the future can push external content and signals into the Office Graph from Line of Business systems and 3rd party services to enrich it even further."

The demo is at about the 30:00 mark.

Answer (score 0):

There has been contact with some people at Microsoft and they told us it isn't possible at the moment, but all the data show that it will be in the future. More will be made known at //Build.

The Connector cards probably will be made available via the Office Group Connectors in your Office365 Outlook account; in a Group, at the top right, there is a button 'Connectors'. I'm guessing you already found those.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have experimented with the Connector cards and I think that your predictions are most likely accurate. I'm still curious about the openTypeExtension. I haven't been able to find any examples of a use case for it.